# How is used Persistent cookie for Identity .net core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

My project is in .net 3.1 and I use IsPersistent for peoples who want my web site remember her connection, with a checkbox on LogIn form.

When a user logged in to my web site I declare a new event of connection in my database to trace users. But if my user check my checkbox "Remember me", which set to seven days sliding, I am not able to trace this user and so my data is a little bit broken. I wish to declare a new event at least one by day.

So my question is, where can I write a code to add a new event when identity recognize his own cookie ?

Best regard
Christopher

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [`OnValidateIdentity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn497603(v=vs.108)) that allows you to validate the cookie as it comes into the application to implement your own logic too:

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnValidateIdentity = context =>
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```